# Unsuccessfully updating Mongoose subdocument

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, subdocument

I currently have a Mongoose schema for `Item` documents, which has a subdocument called linkedItems. The two are defined as follows:

```
const ItemSchema = new Schema({
    description: { type: [String], required: true },
    linkedItems: [linkedItemSchema],
});

const linkedItemSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    title: String,
    score: Number,
    currentNumberOfRatings: Number,
});
```

All linked items have a `score` attribute which stores the strength of the relationship between the parent `Item` document and each `linkedItem`. I have a function `updateLinkedItemRating`, which when passed a new rating, the parent item ID, and the linked item ID, is supposed to update the score of the linked item by averaging in the new score (`currentNumberOfRatings` is the number of ratings that have thus far been averaged into the score). The following piece of code within `updateLinkedItemRating` is supposed to update this score, based on documentation I found on Mongoose subdocuments. It correctly calculates the new score, however the DB is not updated properly and both `err` and `result` in the callback are logging as null. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
Item.findOne({ _id: parentItemId }, function(err, item) {
    // Calculate new average score, this all works fine
    const linkedItem = item.linkedItems.id(linkedItemId);
    const currentTotalNumberOfRatings = linkedItem.currentNumberOfRatings;
    const currentScore = linkedItem.score;
    const newAverageNumerator = parseInt(currentScore) * parseInt(currentTotalNumberOfRatings) + parseInt(rating);
    const newAverageDenominator = parseInt(currentTotalNumberOfRatings) + 1;
    const newAverageScore = newAverageNumerator * 1.0 / newAverageDenominator;

    console.log(newAverageScore); // This logs the proper number
    //This does not update the DB as expected
    Item.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: item._id, 'linkedItems._id': linkedItemId },
        {
            $set: {
                'linkedItems.$.score': newAverageScore,
                'linkedItems.$.currentNumberOfRatings': currentTotalNumberOfRatings + 1,
            },
        },
        function (err, result) {
            console.log(err); // Logs null
            console.log(result); // Logs null
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: What's the use of the `parseInt`, and `* 1.0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need the findOneAndUpdate, as you already have the linkedItem when you do

```
const linkedItem = item.linkedItems.id(linkedItemId);
```

So you could just set those properties and then use .save()

```
linkedItem.score = newAverageScore;
linkedItem.currentNumberOfRatings = currentTotalNumberOfRatings;
item.save(function(err, result){
  console.log(err);
  console.log(result);
});
```